# Is it OK to take absolute value of NSTimeInterval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nstimeinterval

Needed positive time interval taken from given NSDate. Both methods below do that.

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateStart];
timerLbl.text=[[NSDateComponentsFormatter new] stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

OR

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = fabs([dateStart timeIntervalSinceNow]);
timerLbl.text=[[NSDateComponentsFormatter new] stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];
```

Was wondering if the last method was OK. Appreciate your input.

Comment: I don't see why it would cause a problem. `fabs` takes and returns a `Double` - which is essentially what a `TimeInterval` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's ok.

The property `timeIntervalSinceNow` is a computed property of a `Date` instance. It tells you how many seconds in the future a given date is.

If you ask a date in the past how many seconds in the future it is, it will give you an answer that's a negative number.

If instead you want to know how many seconds in the past a date is, use `fabs()`

Comment: I end up writing code that deals with past dates a lot more than future dates. I wish there was a stock property `timeIntervalUntilNow` that would give you the number of seconds a date is from now. Sure, you can convert, but if I had to pick which the two versions I'd like to be built in, it would be `timeIntervalUntilNow`

Comment: BTW, I don't know if I'd include "Of course it's ok" in the answer — I think this question hinges on the fact that OP didn't know that `NSTimeInterval` is an absolute timestamp difference measured in seconds; it only becomes obvious once you know that. :)

Comment: @ItaiFerber I don't agree with you. "Of course it's ok" gives a more Green-works-without-problem indication than "it is OK", which could mean : "it is ok, but should you?" :)

Comment: @Sneak Sure, but if that's the intent, you can also say "Sure, that will work." to mean the same thing. You can confirm this unequivocally without saying "Of course", which can be taken ambiguously. But, just my feeling — didn't edit the answer for this reason.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I understand what you are saying.and I agree that "Sure, that will work" could be taken more straightforward and with ease and still give the same meaning. :)